# ruby installation with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

```
➜  TestApps git:(master) ✗ rvm install 2.1.3
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.25.31', you are using older version '1.25.28'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-2.1.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/test-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.
ruby-2.1.3 - #downloading ruby-2.1.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total &emsp;   % Received % &emsp; Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time  &emsp;   Time  Current
                          &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;       Dload &emsp;  Upload   &emsp; Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 &emsp; 11.4M  &emsp; 100 11.4M  &emsp;   0   &emsp;  0 &emsp;  63269  &emsp;    0  0:03:09  0:03:09 --:--:-- 43967
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.1.3 - #extracting ruby-2.1.3 to /home/test-user/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.3 - please wait
ruby-2.1.3 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.1.3 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.1.3 - #compiling - please wait
```

**Why `rvm` installation showing these below lines:**
    Warning, new version of rvm available '1.25.31', you are using older version '1.25.28'.
    You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
    You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
    Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.
    Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-2.1.3.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Remind you there is a new version for rvm, run `rvm get stable` to update rvm.

Answer (score 1):

It's an advice that there is a newer version of RVM available. You can upgrade with

```
$ rvm get latest
```